# IntelliSense doesn't work with my own React component library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-proptypes

IntelliSense doesn't display props that components in my React library accept. The library is bundled into a UMD module with Webpack (*if that matters*).

Here's what it looks like in my IDE when I try to see what props the component takes:

[image]

Compared to other elements/components...

[image]

How do I get IntelliSense to work with my components?

Comment: Nitpick: From your screenshots, this appears to be a question about an IntelliJ-family IDE; IntelliSense is a feature of Visual Studio (and VS Code).

Comment: I believe IntelliJ uses `propTypes` to gather this information, are you setting this for `Player`?

Comment: @MTCoster Hi, yes. I've set `propTypes` for the `Player` component. IntelliSense doesn't seem to work after bundling the library and importing it in a new project.

Comment: You may need to create a TypeScript definition file (index.d.ts) to tell IntelliJ about your library then.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but hopefully this will help someone.

I had the same problem with my component library that I was building with rollup.

I was using @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, and writing the classes like this:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export default class Alert extends PureComponent {
    static propTypes = {
        type: PropTypes.oneOf(['success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger']),
        title: PropTypes.string,
    }

    render() {
        const { type, children } = this.props


        return (
            <div>
                <h3>{title}</h3>
                {children &&
                <div className="alert-content">
                    {children}
                </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In my compiled file, this used `defineProperty` like this to define the propTypes:

```
_defineProperty(Alert, "propTypes", {
  type: PropTypes.oneOf(['success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger']),
  title: PropTypes.string
});
```

By setting the option `loose: true` on the babel-plugin, I managed to turn it into this, and the intellisense worked in IntelliJ:

```
Alert.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.oneOf(['success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger']),
  title: PropTypes.string
};
```

My .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ]
}
```